# How am I supposed to serve Schiphol with a tram line?

Tags: cities-in-motion

The second mission in the Amsterdam scenario involves running a tram server all the way to Schiphol. Nevermind a station-Schiphol airport service was the very first thing I did. *sigh*

Anyway, I can't actually make this happen because I can't close the line. To make a loop, buses can simply use this roundabout. The game would just like trams to *cut through* the roundabout, but that means there's no way for trams to change direction of travel and turn back.

[image]

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to build the stop much closer to the actual terminal and build outside the street. Avoid that roundabout entirely and you should be fine.

You could've also build the stop a little back, preserving the parking lots there, but the game thinks that's too far from your destination.

[image]

Next time you think parking at Schiphol is hell, now you know why.

**Note**: This task also requires you to raise tram tickets by .20 units. You didn't forget, did you?